# Handling JsonResponse in Django template

Tags: python, json, django, ajax, jsonresponse

I'm trying to make a webpage in which you can specify a number of vectors, then insert modulus and angle for each one, and it will calculate the sum.
My code can do the calculation, but I can't properly display the result on my template.

views.py:

```
def sum_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        message = ''
        for j in range(2,12):
            if not request.POST.get(f'vector_mod_{j}'):
                num_vett = j - 1
                result = Vector(0, 0)
                for i in range(num_vett):
                    mod =  float(request.POST.get(f'vector_mod_{i+1}'))
                    ang = float(request.POST.get(f'vector_ang_{i+1}'))
                    result += Vector(mod, ang)
                    message = f'Modulus: {result.modulus}, angle: {result.angle}°'
                return JsonResponse({'message': message})

    return render(request, 'vectsum/sum.html')
```

The problem is that when I submit I see a sort of firefox developer tools view with a menu including 'JSON', 'Raw Data', 'Headers', and the correct message displayed in a console-like way.

Here is the ajax part of my template:

```
$(document).on('submit','#calculate',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       
           $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
           url:'/vectorialsum/',
           data: $('#calculate').serialize()
           success:function(data){
               var mess = JSON.parse(data)['message']
               document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += mess
               
                   }
           })

       
       });
```

[image: This is the output]

Probably I don't get what return JsonResponse does, however how do I show the message in my page?

Edit:
maybe my question is not clear, I'll rephrase: how can I send back to ajax's success function the `message` variable?

Comment: I guess it could be a problem with return, you get the list or stack in  ```result```, try to apply to c exact instance in stack - `result[0].modulus`, or `result[0]`

Comment: No, both give error, the problem here is not the math, results are correct, I just can't display them in the page.

Comment: What the `result` should be: list, dict, tuple or set? And what is `Vector` here?

Comment: I created the class Vector. result is a Vector, identified by a modulus and an angle, two floats result.modulus and result.angle . But, again, the problem is not that.